# flash.warning is displayed only after page refresh

Tags: jquery, grails, gsp

Hi I have a gsp which will have jq grids and some templates which will be loaded initially.
if there is some thing wrong in the controller It will be throwing flash.warning like

```
def err = resp?.status?.message?:resp?.status?.message?:message(code:'common.unknown.error')
flash.warning = message(code:'common.error.default', args:[err])
```

in the gsp i will be catching it with

```
<div id="errorPanel">
        <g:if test="${flash.warning}">
                <g:message code = "reporting.label" />
                <div class="message">${flash.warning}</div>
    </g:if>
   </div>
```

Every thing is fine if te controller is throwing the warning it is displayed only after page refresh.
Please help me out

my gsp is

```
<%@ page language="java" import="com.cisco.rms.constants.TicketType" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="layout" content="main" />
        <g:set var="entityName" value="${message(code: 'incident.label', default: '<incident.label>')}" />
        <title><g:message code = "incident.list" /></title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <div id="errorPanel">
        <g:if test="${flash.warning}">
                <g:message code = "reporting.label" />
                <div class="message">${flash.warning}</div>
        </g:if>
   </div>
   <div class="ros-pageContainer">
       <div id="incidentListContainer" class="rosPanel">
           <div id="incidentListHeaderContainer">
               <div class="ui-widget-header">
                   <span class="ros-title"> <g:message code="incident.label.plural" /> </span>
                   <g:include controller="ticket" action="searchTicketsInclude"/>
                   <!--
                   <span class="header-quick-action">       
                       <select name="quickactions">
                              <option selected> <g:message code="common.quickActions.header" /> </option>
                              <option value="download"><g:message code="common.quickActions.download" /> </option>
                              <option value="list and details"><g:message code="common.quickActions.listAndDetails" /> </option>
                              <option value="list only"><g:message code="common.quickActions.listOnly" /> </option>
                              <option value="list all"><g:message code="common.quickActions.listAll" /> </option>
                              <option value="print list"><g:message code="common.quickActions.printList" /> </option>
                              <option value="columns"><g:message code="common.quickActions.columns" /> </option>
                       </select>                                    
                   </span> -->
               </div> 
            </div>
            <jqgrid:wrapper id="incident" />
        </div>
        <g:render template="details"/>

        <br/>
        <g:render template="/site/sitesAffected"/>

        <br/>
        <g:render template="/device/listForIncident"/>  
        <br/>
        <g:render template="/workLog/list"/>    
        <br/>

        <g:render template="/alarm/listForIncident"/>

    </div>
    <g:render template="/layouts/gridTemplate" />
    <script type="text/javascript"> 

        function searchByTicketId()
        {
            var ticketId = $('#ticketId').val();
            var id_type = $("input[@name=id_type]:checked").val();;

            var ext = false;
            if(id_type == 'external')
                ext = true;

            search(ticketId, ext);
        }

        function search(ticketId, ext)
        {   
            var grid = $('#incidentGrid');

            grid.jqGrid("clearGridData", true);                 
            grid.jqGrid('setGridParam',{postData:{ticketId:ticketId, extTicketId:ext}});            
            grid.trigger( 'reloadGrid' );

            // alert('ticketId: ' + ticketId + ' type: ' + id_type + ' external: ' + ext);
        }

        function resetSearch()
        {
            $('#ticketId').val('');

            var grid = $('#incidentGrid');
            grid.jqGrid("clearGridData", true)
            grid.jqGrid('setGridParam',{postData:{ticketId:null}});
            grid.trigger( 'reloadGrid' );

        }

        function onIncidentGridComplete() {
            var devCount = $('#incidentGrid').getGridParam("reccount");
            if (devCount == 1) {
                var rowId = $('#incidentGrid').getDataIDs()[0];
                $('#incidentGrid').setSelection(rowId, true);
            }
            $(window).trigger('resize');
        }

        var ticketId;
        var ticketType = '${com.cisco.rms.constants.TicketType.INCIDENT}';

        function quickActions(actionsList)
        {
            var sel = actionsList.selectedIndex

            if(sel == 1)
            {
                window.open('../workLog/addWorkLog?ticketId=' + ticketId + '&ticketType=' + ticketType, 'Add Worklog', 'width=600,height=600', false)
            }               
        }

        function resizeGrid(){
            //$('#incidentGrid').jqGrid('setGridHeight',$(window).outerHeight() - 255 - 25 - $("#incidentDetailsContainer").outerHeight());
        }

        function clearDetails() {
            clearIncDetails();
        }

        function onSelectRow(rowId) {
            clearDetails();
            $('#quickActions').show();

            ticketId = $('#incidentGrid').getCell(rowId, 'id');
            populateDetails(rowId);

            var rowMinus1 = parseInt(rowId) - 1;
            $("#incidentGrid tr").removeClass("ui-state-highlight-1");
            $("#incidentGrid tr:eq(" + rowMinus1 + ")").addClass("ui-state-highlight-1");
            resizeGrid();

            reloadDeviceGrid(ticketId);
            reloadWorklogs (ticketId, ticketType);
            reloadSitesAffectedGrid(ticketId, ticketType);
            reloadAlarms(ticketId);
        }

        function populateDetails(rowId) {
            var grid = $('#incidentGrid');
            var id = grid.getCell(rowId, 'id');
            var submitDate = grid.getCell(rowId, 'submitDate');
            var summary = grid.getCell(rowId, 'summary');
            var status = grid.getCell(rowId, 'status');
            var type = grid.getCell(rowId, 'type');

            var data = {id:id, submitDate:submitDate, summary:summary, status:status, type:type};
            populateIncDetails(data);
        }




        $(document).ready(function() {

            <jqgrid:grid
                id="incident"
                url="'${createLink(action: 'listByCompanyJSON', params: [ticketId: params.ticketId])}'"
                colNames="
                    '${g.message( code:'common.priority' )}',
                    '${g.message( code:'common.id' )}',
                    '${g.message( code:'user.details.site' )}',
                    '${g.message( code:'common.impact' )}',
                    '${g.message( code:'incident.opened' )}',
                    '${g.message( code:'common.parameters.duration' )}',
                    '${g.message( code:'common.status' )}',
                    '${g.message( code:'common.description' )}',
                    '${g.message( code:'common.type' )}'
                "
                colModel="
                    {name:'priority', editable: false, fixed: true, width:'55px'},
                    {name:'id', editable: false, fixed: true, width:'100px'},
                    {name:'siteName', editable: false, fixed: true, classes:'ellipsis', width: '200px'},
                    {name:'impact', editable: false, fixed: true, width:'125px'},
                    {name:'submitDate', editable: false, fixed:true, width:'125px'},
                    {name:'duration', editable: false, fixed:true, width:'95px'},
                    {name:'status', editable: false, fixed: true, width:'65px'},
                    {name:'summary', editable: false, classes:'ellipsis' },
                    {name:'type', editable: false, hidden: true}
                "

                gridComplete="onIncidentGridComplete"
                onSelectRow="onSelectRow"
                resizable="true"
                sortname="'id'"
                sortorder="'desc'"
                height="265"
                autowidth="true"
                shrinkToFit="true"
                scrollOffset="16"
                viewrecords="true"
                showPager="true"
                rowNum="12"
                datatype="'json'">
                <jqgrid:navigation  id="incident"   refresh="true" />
                <jqgrid:resize id="incident" resizeOffset="0" />
            </jqgrid:grid>

            //Strips garbage from grid
            $("#incidentListContainer").find("#incidentWrapper").first().removeClass("ui-widget-header");

            //Wires window resize so grid will fit properly at all sizes
            $(window).resize(resizeGrid);

            $(window).trigger('resize');



        }

        );

        </script>
</body>   
</html>
```

Comment: This 'error checking' is done before or after viewing the gsp for the first time ?

Comment: on page load the templetes are loaded and later controller is called and if some thing fails in controller the error should be handled and dsplayed to the user

Answer (score 1):

This is because the the flash object is only available on the next request, hence only after a page refresh. You can read about it here -> http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/flash.html

Are you trying to use Ajax? I am not sure about Grails 2.x but when I used Grails 1.3.7, we had to create a workaround to force the message to come out without using the flash scope.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the behabiour you're expecting:

```
load page A -> call controller -> see flash.warning on page A
```

Then I'm afraid you'll have to figure out some other way of displaying the message. Also, the flash object does not work when doing ajax calls.

If you want to do it with ajax you can use `params` inside a template instead:

```
<g:if test="${params?.variable}"> ...
```